# Access to a server on a Parallels VM

Tags: networking, virtualization, virtual-machine, parallels

I've installed Parallels with an Ubuntu VM. In the Ubuntu VM I've installed an Oracle lite database and other services on other ports.

Now from OS X, I want to access to my Linux VM.

- Can I use 'shared network'?
- What IP address I have to use? What port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your IP using `ifconfig` both in your Linux or Mac boxes.

Comment: this is not the answer, i have the same problem and can't get it to work even looking virtual eth interfaces with ifconfig u.u, there is some kind of NAT within parallels, even added port forwarding and didn't worked...

Answer (score -1):

select bridged network and check ifconfig on ubuntu vm, something like 192.168.0.X
should be accessible on mac as well
works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).